# How does template matching work?

Tags: c#, image-processing, face-recognition

I have an array of pixels and I would like to search through it to see if there is a specific template.
But I am unsure how to start - for each pixel run the search for the template image? I cannot imagine how it could work if e.g. First 5 pixels match and the sixth does not, should it move back to second pixel and start over> Also I assume some kind of tolerance must be there.

Comment: it's a bit hard to understand your problem for me.. but have you read many articles available out there? since you are asking about how template matching works: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the Accord.NET Extensions library which implements fast template matching algorithm along with some samples.

Fast template matching algorithm:
Gradient Response Maps for Real-Time Detection of Textureless Objects
[Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6042881)

The library:
https://github.com/dajuric/accord-net-extensions

source:
https://github.com/dajuric/accord-net-extensions/tree/master/Source/ImageProcessing/FastTemplateMatching

There is an example too.